# How to retrieve values from multilevel json

Tags: php, json

Im trying to get the values from the various sections of this json entry.

```
{
    "gallery_show": "1",
    "gallery": {
        "path": ["images\/slide2.jpg", "images\/slide1.jpg", "images\/slide2.jpg", "images\/slide1.jpg", "images\/slide2.jpg", "images\/slide1.jpg"],
        "title": ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
        "caption": ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
        "thumb": ["\/admin\/cache\/thumbs_200x150\/slide2_200x150.jpg", 
        "\/admin\/cache\/thumbs_200x150\/slide1_200x150.jpg", 
        "\/admin\/cache\/thumbs_200x150\/slide2_200x150.jpg", 
        "\/admin\/cache\/thumbs_200x150\/slide1_200x150.jpg", 
        "\/admin\/cache\/thumbs_200x150\/slide2_200x150.jpg", 
        "\/admin\/cache\/thumbs_200x150\/slide1_200x150.jpg"]
    },
    "videos_show": "1",
    "videos": {
        "title": ["Arnie", "Arnie", "Arnie", "Arnie", "Arnie"],
        "sharelink": ["http:\/\/youtu.be\/7kTz6MVrBlY", "http:\/\/youtu.be\/7kTz6MVrBlY", "http:\/\/youtu.be\/7kTz6MVrBlY", "http:\/\/youtu.be\/7kTz6MVrBlY", "http:\/\/youtu.be\/7kTz6MVrBlY"]
    },
    "attachments_show": "1",
    "attachments": {
        "path": ["images\/slide2.jpg", "images\/slide1.jpg"],
        "title": ["Attchment", "Attchment"],
        "caption": ["Attachment Description", "Attachment Description"]
    },
    "links_show": "1",
    "links": {
        "title": ["Link1", "Link2"],
        "httplink": ["http:\/\/www.mydomain.com", "http:\/\/www.mydomain.com"],
        "targetlink": ["_blank", "_blank"]
    }
}
```

If i use this method

```
$entries= json_decode($this->item->entries);
```

and then i echo this

```
echo $entries->gallery_show;
```

I get the desired result = 1

But how do i now get the things beneath it if gallery_show=1 and display them as values i can use inside my php?

Any help for this old brain would be much appreciated.

Cheers in advance
Jonny

Comment: you can convert json string to array format by passing TRUE as second parameter in json_decode function like json_decode($json_str,TRUE)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback PravinS, i did have a look at what you said but i gave Shankar the tick as his idea did come first and worked a treat. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do somewhat like this...

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    if($k=='gallery_show' && $v==1)
    {
        foreach($arr->gallery->path as $path)
        {
            echo "<img src=$path />";
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/119267)

#### Code update..

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    if($k=='gallery_show' && $v==1)
    {

        foreach($arr->gallery as $gall)
        {

            echo "Title :".$arr->gallery->title[$i]."<br/>";
            echo "Caption :".$arr->gallery->caption[$i]."<br/>";
            echo "Thumbnail :".$arr->gallery->thumb[$i]."<br>";
            echo "<img src=".$arr->gallery->path[$i]." /><br>";
            $i++;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/119273)

Comment: Thank you Shankar, that definitely gives me an output to work with, however now how do i turn that into usable data like so?

<img src="<?php echo $imgpath;?>"/>

Comment: So basically you want to output the images to the browser if the gallery_show is 1 .. right ?

Comment: @jonnypixel, I have modified the code and added a demo for you.

Comment: thank you! you are amazing. Where are you based? can we stay in touch maybe? Im in Australia.

Comment: hey the only thing is how do i echo the title and caption i tried just adding $arr->gallery->title but all i got was the word array

Comment: @jonnypixel, Added the new code as requested.. Included a demo too. As there is no title and caption in the JSON , you will see just a blank text. I have also added a thumbnail, incase if you need it.

Comment: i kind of have a problem. It only does it 4 times - because teh top level json decode is only 4 headings